# Migrating Indesign

Tags: lyx, conversion, import

I've been producing a technical book in Lyx.
I've decided that for this work, I'ld be better off using Adobe Indesign.
it need allot of complex layout/graphical stuff.
Like timelines, sidebars, complex tables 
(I have some tables, but I want to do things like put text in a smaller font underneath the text I've got, which LyX's GUI doesn't support).
Even ignoring those reasons learning InDesign is useful, in it's own right.

I guess I want to turn my Parts, or chapters into Documents.

I know InDesign has some stuff for importing XML, thought I'm not to clues up on that.
So perhaps I can Export to Tex and then Convert to XML?
Then import the XML into InDesign?
Or am I better off doing it manually:
Export to text file, and copy and paste. Recreating layout and tables manaually?

Comment: This http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/adobe-indesign/message/3680
Suggested that manual is the best way